# Working with BigIntegers in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, biginteger

I am testing out BigIntegers.

When I take a large odd number and divide it by 2, I get an integer as an anwser, without any indication that it could not divide the number exactly.

So first question is how do I know that two numbers divide exactly.

I then tested it with a small number, an this code:

```
        string myNumberAsString = "25";
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] myNumberAsByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(myNumberAsString);
        BigInteger myNumber = new BigInteger(myNumberAsByteArray);
        Console.WriteLine(myNumber / 2);
```

Gives the result 6809. Anybody know why or can see what is wrong with my code?

I am using the .net 4.0 implementation of BigInteger

Comment: I don't think that encoding to UTF8 will give you a byte array representing the number 25?

Comment: 6809 in hex is 0x1A99, which is exactly half of 0x3532.  The ASCII codes (UTF-8 uses ASCII codes for characters in the ASCII range) for the characters in your string are 0x32 and 0x35, which due to little-endian byte order, become 0x3532.  So your "big integer" isn't odd, and division is giving you the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the string-to-BigInteger conversion problems that others have pointed out, dividing two BigIntegers always yields a BigInteger result (since integers don't have a fractional component). This result will be the integer part of whatever the floating-point result would have been.

To determine whether the division was exact or not, use the [DivRem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem.aspx) method:

```
var dividend = BigInteger.Parse("25");

BigInteger remainder;
var quotient = BigInteger.DivRem(dividend, 2, out remainder);
if (!remainder.IsZero) {
    throw new Exception("Division resulted in remainder of " + remainder + "!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what implementation of `BigInteger` you are using but `myNumberAsByteArray` will not contain the bytes representing the number `25`. You are simply converting a string to bytes here. You could have used string `myNumberAsString = "abc";` which would have given you another result.

You probably want to use the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231.aspx) method instead:

```
BigInteger myNumber = BigInteger.Parse("25");
```

Comment: `BigInteger` is part of System.Numerics since .Net 4

Comment: @Cameron, I know this, but the OP should have specified it. There are also other possible implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If you must convert from a string representation of a number, use `BigInteger.TryParse` or `BigInteger.Parse`.

But regardless of how you instantiate your `BigInteger`, you can determine if a number is evenly divisible by another by using modular math.  For example, if you want to see if `someNumber` is divisible by 2, then just verify that `(someNumber % 2) == 0` (i.e., sumNumber / 2 has a remainder of zero).  This works for any integer denominator.  Just replace `2` with which ever denominator you want to test.  With `BigInteger`, though, you should probably use the `DivRem` method instead of the % operator.

Comment: I take back what I said about DivRem.  That isn't really necessary, but certainly acceptable.  The modulus operator (%) is fine.  Just try to avoid implicit data type conversions when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating how you construct the `BigInteger` - the framework provides implicit casts from `byte`, `Int16`, etc:

```
BigInteger myNumber = 25;
Console.WriteLine(myNumber / 2);
```

To convert larger numbers from a string representation, use `BigInteger.Parse()`:

```
BigInteger myNumber = BigInteger.Parse("252525252525252525252525252525");
Console.WriteLine(myNumber / 2);
```